# Email function does not work after put in a class

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

So basically I copy and pasted an email sending python script which works. This is the code:

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = 'email@email.com'
gmail_password = 'P@ssword!'

sent_from = gmail_user
to = ['bill@gmail.com']
subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'
body = 'Hey, whats up?\n\n- You'

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print ('Email sent!')
except:
    print ('Something went wrong...')
```

The result is as perfectly described: [image]

Unfortunately, I put the code within a class to execute as a function from another main function. Code is as below:

```
import smtplib

class EmailSending():
    def doneEmail(self):

        gmail_user = 'email@email.com'
        gmail_password = 'P@ssword!'

        sent_from = gmail_user
        to = ['bill@gmail.com']
        subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'
        body = 'Hey, whats up?\n\n- You'

        email_text = """\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s

        %s
        """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
            server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
            server.close()

            print('Email sent!')
        except:
            print('Something went wrong...')

ef = EmailSending()
ef.doneEmail()
```

The only code that changed is that it is now in a class function.
But when calling it, it returns a different result, shown below
[image]

The email still sends to my email but everything else is out. Can anyone help me out? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added spaces at the beginnings of the lines containing `From:` and so on. Remove them:

```
class EmailSending():
    def doneEmail(self):

        gmail_user = 'email@email.com'
        gmail_password = 'P@ssword!'

        sent_from = gmail_user
        to = ['bill@gmail.com']
        subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'
        body = 'Hey, whats up?\n\n- You'

        email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
            server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
            server.close()

            print('Email sent!')
        except:
            print('Something went wrong...')

ef = EmailSending()
ef.doneEmail()
```

Comment: Works, holy crap! How could I miss that error, thanks!